# Bringing up all man page sections for a program at once

Tags: linux, centos, man, qmail, system-administration

when I type `man qmail` I get `No manual entry for qmail`.  I would like to be able to type `man qmail` and one screen opens up that includes all the man sections for qmail.

Is there a way I can open up man1, man5, man7, man8 all at once and then make that command an alias so that I type in "man qmail" and all the documentation related to qmail opens up?

[This article](https://superuser.com/questions/581556/man-page-command-man-3-vs-man) was useful on man knowledge

Same with this image:

[image: Man page segmentation diagram]

Comment: Lesson 0: `man man`. It should read "the default action is to search in all of the available sections […], and to show only the first page found". This means if `man qmail` is telling you `No manual entry for qmail` then it's giving you *all* manual pages for `qmail` it knows of: namely zero. Is `man -a` (e.g. `man -a intro`) good enough? It should give you "all the man sections for", not as "one screen" though.

Answer (score 1):

**To directly answer the question**: `man -a (whatever)` may be what you're looking for - this will sequentially and interactively bring up all man pages that match the text you enter, but it will likely bring up way more than you actually wanted.

**But your problem is different**. Your error message indicates that you have no manpages for `qmail` available.

First, ensure that the appropriate manpage packages are installed via `yum`. For CentOS 6 these are the packages `man man-pages`. For 7 and 8, use `man-pages man-db man`.

If those commands installed anything, try `man qmail` again.

One thing to note about qmail, is that its documentation is spread out since qmail uses multiple different segmented applications to handle mail delivery. `man qmail` will bring up the top-level documentation, and therein you'll be given the names of the other programs which have their own pages such as `qmail-control` and `qmail-read`.